# Synchronizing callbacks between different threads in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, callback

I am still relatively new to java and Android and am working with the Android sample code MediaBrowserService.

I utilized that code to understand how a MediaController and MediaSession work together.  Callbacks are used in that use pattern.  What I also saw in that example is that user defined classes also make use of the Callback paradigm.

I have a question about the thread limitations about this.
For example, the following is declared in the public class MusicProvider:

```
public interface Callback {
void onMusicCatalogReady(boolean success);
}
```

with the following references in the same class:

```
private void retrieveMediaAsync(Callback callback) {
    initializationLock.lock();
        //...
        //code removed
        //...
        if (callback != null) {
            Log.w(" CB_REF1",":");

            callback.onMusicCatalogReady(mCurrentState == State.INITIALIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
public void retrieveMedia(final Callback callback) {
        //...
        //code removed
        //...
        Log.w(" CB_REF2",":");
        callback.onMusicCatalogReady(true);
        return;
    }
```

Then in public class MusicService (extends MediaBrowserService) there are the following definitions:

```
public void onCreate() {
    //...
    //code removed
    //...
    super.onCreate();
    Log.w(" CB_DEF2",":");
    mMusicProvider.retrieveMedia(new MusicProvider.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onMusicCatalogReady(boolean success) {

            mState = success ? PlaybackState.STATE_NONE : PlaybackState.STATE_ERROR;
        }
    });
```

and:

```
public void onLoadChildren(final String parentMediaId, final Result<List<MediaItem>> result) {
        //...
        //code removed
        //...

        Log.w(" CB_DEF1",":");
        mMusicProvider.retrieveMedia(new MusicProvider.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onMusicCatalogReady(boolean success) {

                if (success) {
                    loadChildrenImpl(parentMediaId, result);
                } else {
                    updatePlaybackState(getString(R.string.error_no_metadata));
                    result.sendResult(new ArrayList<MediaItem>());
                }
            }
        });
```

I then ran the application with the following output in the Logcat window:

```
03-01 12:19:32.607    1929-1929/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_DEF2﹕ :
03-01 12:19:32.794    1929-1929/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_DEF2﹕ :
03-01 12:19:32.957    1929-1929/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_DEF1﹕ :
03-01 12:19:33.294    1929-2053/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_REF1﹕ :
03-01 12:19:45.329    1929-1929/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_DEF2﹕ :
03-01 12:19:45.347    1929-1929/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_DEF1﹕ :
03-01 12:19:45.426    1929-2033/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_REF1﹕ :
03-01 12:19:45.428    1929-2033/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_REF1﹕ :
03-01 12:19:47.622    1929-1929/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_DEF2﹕ :
03-01 12:19:47.643    1929-1929/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_DEF1﹕ :
03-01 12:19:47.732    1929-2053/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_REF1﹕ :
03-01 12:19:47.734    1929-2033/com.example.android.mediabrowserservice W/CB_REF1﹕ :
```

So I can see (and somewhat understand) how the callback function is redefined as required by means of registering the particular definition as a callback.

My question is related to the behavior with respect to multithreading.

Does  the ability to register different callback methods, imply all of these registrations must occur in the same thread as the invocation of the callback to make sure the callback registration is not in some intermediate state when the callback is called?

If this isn't the case then is seems to me that when the callback was called the instruction to register the callback could be in some intermediate state and I've not sure how this would be handled within the Android environment.

Thank you for considering my question.
Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android follows the single-thread model, which is to say, all UI-related operations occur on the main thread only, and all non-UI operations need explicitly be performed on a separate thread. And so thread synchronization for callbacks is not something that most people seem to talk about. It *would* be necessary to do so if we were sending a callback between operations on two different threads. The single thread policy is adopted by the framework designers precisely *because* thread synchronization is a thorny subject for most programmers.

You do raise an interesting question, and by way of answer, examples of callbacks that are synchronized in such a way (by the framework) are:

- the `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()` methods of `AsyncTask`.
- the `onResponse()` and `onError()` methods of a Volley `Request`.

However, none of these are true interface callbacks of the type you describe. Those are virtual methods overriden in a derived class. I have to admit that I've *never* seen an *interface* callback synchronized between two threads in Android app development thus far.